# Timeout on SerialPort.BaseStream

Tags: .net, serial-port

I've tried different approaches to reading from a SerialPort-object. The SerialPort-class seems somewhat unstable (i.e. BytesToRead-property) so I thought I might want to use the BaseStream-property of the SerialPort-object.

Since I don't know the lenght of the data in advance I make use of the fact that my data is delimited by two \r. This signifies the end of the data. Timeout of the BaseStream is 2000 ms.

Now, what happens is that the program reads all data until it stalls at ReadAsync(). My guess is that the ReadAsync()-method is waiting for data to fill up the buffer. This is not the described behavior as I would expect bytesRead just to be smaller than BUFF_SIZE if "Lenght of data" % BUFF_SIZE != 0.

Can anyone tell me why my code doesn't behave as expected and maybe point me in the right direction :) ?

Best regards

Frederik

CODE:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var bStream = serialPort.BaseStream;
var buff = new byte[BUFF_SIZE];
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        var bytesRead = await bStream.ReadAsync(buff, 0, BUFF_SIZE);
        var bytes = buff.Take(bytesRead);
        var str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes.ToArray());

        sb.Append(str);

        var sbLen = sb.Length;
        if (sb.Length > 2 && sb[sbLen - 2] == '\r' && sb[sbLen - 1] == '\r')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        log.AppendLine(String.Format("Timed out after {0} char", sb.Length));
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's buggy code.  You blindly assume that the last 2 received characters are "\r\r".  That's not how serial ports work, you get whatever is available in the driver's receive buffer.  So non-zero odds, particularly when you debug, that you get too much and `sb` contains "\r\r" *plus* characters from the next "line".  You'll have to fix this by searching for "\r\r" from the start of the buffer and preserve anything beyond it.  And the simplest approach is to set the serialport's NewLine property to "\r\r" and use ReadLine() instead.

Comment: And if you get a TimeoutException then consider that you are not receiving anything at all.  Usually caused by setting the Handshake property to None.

Comment: Hi Hans. Thank you for your response. I see your point and I think the search-approach is more robust. Regarding the ReadLine(): This would block my UI-thread and make it unresponsive. I'd like to use the Async-methods for this very reason. Any Ideas why the ReadAync() stalls?

Comment: The DataReceived event is asynchronous.  ReadAsync() stalls when you don't receive anything.